# Resetting the IP address of a router without using the web interface

Tags: networking, router, windows-10, ip, ipconfig

I recently purchased an Asus rt n12e-b1 to use as an access point or repeater, expanding my network's range.

I had it semi-working until I decided to fiddle with the IP address, assigning it to 192.168.2.255. From what I've read, IP addresses generally shouldn't end in 255 and after the change I couldn't access the web interface anymore.

I've tried reinstalling the firmware, resetting the tcp/ip stack and resetting WINSOCK entries to defaults with no avail.

Every time I try `ipconfig /release` I get an error saying that no operation can be performed while the media is disconnected.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Usually routers have a "reset-to-factory-state" button on them somewhere. See if yours does.

Comment: Yes, a last octet of `.255` in an IP address on a device will be a broadcast **depending on your subnet mask** for example /23 versus /24 or 255.255.254.0 vs 255.255.255.0 . Did you set this IP address on your router or on your PC? It sounds like you say it's your router but then you're running Windows commands like you're trying to reset something on the PC with the IP address. Was it the routers actual IP address or something related to the DHCP pool in the router or what? What did you change specifically that you remember, what did it say, in what system, and any other detail?

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE The windows commands were just potential solutions I had found on forums. I don't know very much about networking so bear with me. I specifically changed the ip address from 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.255 in the web interface. After this I couldn't access it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I reset IP address of a router without using the web interface?

Factory reset your router.

---

#### RT-N12 B1

[image]

Source [RT-N12 B1 User Manual](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/84590.pdf), Page 8

---

#### RT-N12 D1 & HP

> [image]

Source [RT-N12 Series User Guide](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/RT-N12_D1/E7901_RTN12_D1_Manual.pdf), Page 8

Comment: That doesn't work mate. And that isn't my route, I have the B1.

Comment: @McLegendary This should be close enough though even if it's not exactly the same [Asus](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN12E/). If the button isn't resetting it to the factory defaults, then it may be defective or else it wasn't something on the router which you put the broadcast IP address octet in that caused the problem. Pressing that and following that procedure should put it in the state as if you were taking it out of the box from the store (factory defaults).

Comment: @McLegendary The procedure is the same. The button is in a slightly different place and is labelled "Restore" instead of the odd graphic symbol. See updated answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill It still doesn't work

Comment: @McLegendary You now need to configure your PC to talk to the default IP address of the access point. I would use a LAN connection for this...

Comment: @DavidPostill And how would I do that? The router isn't picked up by the asus device discover as well.

Comment: @McLegendary Read the user manual. It tells you how to set up the device. What ever you did last time you have to do all over as you reset the device.